# `child_process.execSync` does not finish until the window is closed

Tags: node.js, windows

`a.bat` file is:

```
@echo off

start "" notepad.exe

echo foobar
```

Running `cmd /c a.bat` in the command prompt opens the Notepad window.
And `foobar` is printed before closing the window.
I can run a next command without closing Notepad.

However, in node.js `child_process.execSync`, the `execSync` function does not end until the
window is closed.
In the following code, the result of console.log is output after the window is closed.

```js
console.log(child_process.execSync(`cmd /c a.bat`))
```

Why does this happen?
Is it possible to get around it without using asynchronous functions like exec or spawn?

Comment: What happens if you use `exec` rather than `execSync`?

Comment: If I replace execSync with exec, `ChildProcess` instance is printed to the console immediately.

Comment: Is this what you expect, or would you like to achieve something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got expected result by

```
console.log(cp.execSync(`cmd /c a.bat`, { stdio: "inherit" }))

// or 

console.log(cp.execSync(`cmd /c a.bat`, { stdio: "ignore" }))
```